# mysqli not working on a livesite

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

please mysqli where working formally but nt working again

```
          <?php
     $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','social') OR die ('Could         not                to  MySQL:' .mysqli_error($dbc) );
   mysqli_select_db($dbc,'social')  OR die ('Could not select db: ' .mysqli_error($dbc) );

    ?>
```

it shows this error Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /home/unilorin/public_html/func/mysql.php on line 2

Comment: can you provide the contents of your <?php phpinfo() ?>

Comment: i am there what should i check

Comment: if you have something similar to http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/img/626144-1092012115402AM

Comment: @bolaji check to see if mysqli is active on your server, see the picture attached above

Comment: I suggest you try using a socket/named pipe instead, is it possible the server doesn't run on tcp/ip and has a non-default socket name?

Answer (score 0):

The [MySQLi extension](http://php.net/mysqli) is probably not installed. You can check this be searching your phpinfo() for the extension.

If not I would suggest using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) (if available) or finding another hosting provider.